# Is there another way to do this without using macro define?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

i have write a function like this

```
int funA(){
//this define is to do something with a,b....z 
#define _MyMacro_ do{\
a....\
b,a...\
z....\
...\
}while(0); 

int a;
char b;
....
float z;

....
if(condition){
_MyMacro_;
}
else if(condition2){
  a++;//just change value
  ...//do some change to a,b,z

  if(...){
     _MyMacro_;
  }
  else{...}
    }

//do something with a,b,...z

_MyMacro_;

...    

}
```

i think it's not a good way to use #define 
if i use function

```
void subfunc(int &a,char &b,.....,float &z)
```

maybe it's better,but has a lot of params

i want to know a better way to do this ,thank you

Comment: That's a lot of ...s and it's hard to see what you're trying to do.  A lambda capturing `a` through `z` might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using functions are the most suited for modularizing your code and the compiler is ready for dealing with them, it doesn't matter the amount of parameters. Macros should be used mostly for configuring compilation variants.

Notice that you can always groups parameters with structs.

Comment: Grouping the variables into structs in a way that organizes them and matches the goal of the program is the way to go.